# How unselect a feature ithat select with OpenLayers-3.8.2's selectInteraction?

Tags: openlayers, ol-interaction

I'm using OpenLayers-3.8.2. I want to select a feature and then delete it. my code is as follow:

```
deleteFeature = function(event){
    var feature = event.selected[0];
    myLayer.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
}

selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
    toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly,
    layers: [myLayer]
})

map.addInteraction(selectInteraction);

selectInteraction.on("select", deleteFeature, this);
```

This code delete the feature from source but it still showed in map.

**How can I unselect a feature**? **Or how can I redraw a layer**? Or how can I delete a featrue in openlayers-3?

Comment: Give some feedback on your questions!

Comment: I update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `clear` function.
Change `deleteFeature` function as follow:

```
deleteFeature = function(event){
    var feature = event.selected[0];
    myLayer.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
    event.selected.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 19):

On ol3 3.11.2, the `event.selected.clear();` does not exist, so you need to use the `selectionInteraction.getFeatures().clear();`

Comment: That unselect all the features selected. 
If you have a selected feature before and then select a new one, will unselect all the features selected.

Answer (score 2):

In open layers 5.2, you can unselect a feature like this:

`deleteFeature = function (event) {
    var feature = event.selected[0];
    myLayer.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
    selectInteraction.getFeatures().remove(feature);
}`